# Hi with i18next it will not load the key

Tags: javascript, i18next, astrojs

I get the title mentioned error when using i18next.
here is my i18n.ts

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-chained-backend';
import LocalStorageBackend from 'i18next-localstorage-backend';
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';

export function initI18n() {
    i18next
        .use(Backend)
        .init({
            backend: {
                backends: [
                    LocalStorageBackend,
                    HttpApi
                ],
                backendOptions: [{
                    debug: true,
                    fallbackLng: "en",
                    lng: 'de',
                }, {
                    debug: true,
                    fallbackLng: "en",
                    lng: 'de',
                    loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json'
                }],
                debug: true
            }
        })
}
```

this is my index astro

```
--- 

import Banner from '../components/Banner.astro';
import Header from '../components/Header.astro';
import {initI18n} from '../i18n/i18n.js'
import Navigation from '../components/Navigation.astro';
 ---
{initI18n()}
<html lang="de">
<Header pageTitle="Sternschnuppe Osterholz Scharmbeck"/>
<body>
    <Banner />
    <Navigation />
</body>
</html>
```

the locales are in folder public/locales/LNG
here the translation.json for de

```
{
    "button": {
        "save": "Speichere {{count}} Änderung",
        "save_plural": "Speichere {{count}} Änderungen"
    },
    "pagetitle": "Sternschnuppe Osterholz Scharmbeck"
```

and this my Navigation.asto

```
---
import i18next from 'i18next';
---
<a href="/">{i18next.t('pagetitle')</a>
<a href="/about/">About</a>
<a href="/blog/">Blog</a>
```

But it only renders the key as is. Not the translation associated with the key.